Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server Expected server HTML contain a matching <div> in <div>
I am getting the above error with the below markup in screenshot.
Screenshot given
I am using Nextjs 14 app router. I tried to pass some server components through a client component which worked fine but after i added another component in suspense i am facing this error. I am using Chakra UI and there is no div in my code. I don't know what could be the solution. Below is my code:
Careers Page
const Careers = () => {
  return (
    <Flex
      direction={"column"}
      w={"90%"}
      mx={"auto"}
      bgColor={"white"}
      pt={24}
      pb={36}
      gap={40}  
      maxW={1300}
      overflow={"clip"}
    >
      {/* Passing the rest of our server components through the client components of this page */}
      {/* This way they will still be server components */}

      <ClientServerBridge>
        <TeamImageGrid />
        <Mission />
        <CultureValues />
        <HowWeThink />
        <WhatsInItForYou />
      </ClientServerBridge>
      {/* this suspense is causing this issue to fix it  */}
      <>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
          <CJobs />
        </Suspense>
      </>
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default Careers;

ClientServerBridge
const ClientServerBridge = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
  const openPosRef = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement>(null);

  const handlePositionClick = () => {
    if (openPosRef.current) {
      openPosRef.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: "smooth",
        block: "center",
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <BecomeAPart OnPositionClick={handlePositionClick} />
      {children}
      <OpenPositions openPosRef={openPosRef} />
    </section>
  );
};

export default ClientServerBridge;

CJobs
const Authorization = `Basic ${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_TOKEN}`;

async function getJobs(): Promise<Response> {
  const res = await fetch("https://app.weatherwalay.com/web/jobs/activeJobs", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { Authorization },
  });

  return res.json();
}

export default async function CJobs() {
  const allJobs = await getJobs();

  return (
    <Accordion
      mt={"16"}
      mx={"auto"}
      w={{ base: "100%", md: "100%" }}
      allowToggle
    >
      {allJobs?.success && allJobs?.record.length > 0 ? (
        allJobs.record?.map((job: Job, i: number) => (
          <JobItem key={"jobs" + i} job={job} />
        ))
      ) : (
        <Center>
          <Text>No Jobs Available Currently</Text>
        </Center>
      )}
    </Accordion>
  );
}

Lastly this is the jobitem
const JobItem = ({ job, handleApply }: JobItemType) => {
  return (
    <AccordionItem mb={"5"} borderWidth={"2px"} rounded={"xl"}>
      <AccordionButton
        _focus={{
          boxShadow: "none",
        }}
      >
        <HStack spacing={"6"}>
          <Heading
            py={"3"}
            pl={"1"}
            fontSize={"20px"}
            as={"h2"}
            flex="1"
            textAlign="left"
            color={blueBrandColor}
          >
            {job?.jobTitle}
          </Heading>
          <HStack color={"grey"} display={{ base: "none", md: "flex" }}>
            <Text>{job?.deprarment}</Text>
            <Divider
              orientation="vertical"
              height={"15px"}
              borderColor={"blackAlpha.500"}
            />
            <Text>{job?.designation}</Text>
          </HStack>
        </HStack>

        <AccordionIcon ml={"auto"} />
      </AccordionButton>

      <AccordionPanel pl={"5"} pb={"8"} pt={"5"}>
        <VStack align={"start"}>
          <Heading
            as={"h3"}
            fontSize={"md"}
            // color={"blackAlpha.800"}
            bg={"cyan.100"}
            px={"2"}
            py={"1"}
            rounded={"full"}
            // styles={{ px: "2", py: "1", rounded: "full", bg: "teal.100" }}
          >
            Requirements
          </Heading>
          {/* <Divider height={"15px"} borderColor={"blackAlpha.600"} /> */}
          {/* <Box
            p={"2"}
            pl={"5"}
            color={"blackAlpha.800"}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: job?.requirements }}
          /> */}
        </VStack>

        <Button onClick={() => handleApply(job)} mt={"10"} colorScheme={"blue"}>
          Apply Now
        </Button>
      </AccordionPanel>
    </AccordionItem>
  );
};


I have tried changing my structure a few times. I tried to remove the suspense and cjobs component, it works fine without that. I dont know a better way to do this or to get rid of this error.

It might be <CJob>, it's a server component but you were using NEXT_PUBLIC variables which is accessed by browser. Try rename it without prefix.
